# Why the resources don't appear in the production server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm developing an app using umbraco cms and AngularJS framework.
Why my web app don't work like a local?... I kept the same structure of permissions and configurations.

Production server conf: win 7 sp1, iis 7.5
Dev server conf: win 8.1 update 1, iis 8.5

Look the picture:

[image: Difference between app running in a production server (right) and in a dev server]

Comment: Is this the back-end of the front end you are showing?

Comment: It's the umbraco backoffice displayed in the Google Chrome Inspector/Debuger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco uses Client Dependency when the compilation mode is not set to debug. The reason they are different is most likely because you have different configurations for debug and release.

If you want to avoid Client dependency, open your Web.config and set:

```
<compilation debug="true" ... >
```

This, is not recommended in a production enviroment, though

Comment: If it works well with debug=true, you should verify disk writing permissions.